# Eclipse Contextual Help

Tags: eclipse-gef

Now can I register contextual help in an Eclipse WizardDialog/Editor.

1) I created a help_contexts.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?NLS TYPE="org.eclipse.help.contexts"?>
<contexts>
   <context  id="my.plugin.help.general" >
        <description>test</description>
        <topic label="test" href="http://domain.com/help.html"/>
   </context>
</contexts>
```

2) I referenced this file in my plugin.xml

```
  <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
         <contexts file="help_contexts.xml" plugin="my.plugin.MainEditor">
         </contexts>
   </extension>
```

3) I added a line in my build.properties to include this file in the bin directory (bin.includes = help_contexts.xml, ... )

4) When running my GEF-based plugin, I see "No match found for "my.plugin.MainEditor"" under dynamic help.

I know I need to create something like this somewhere, but I don't know where to set this up for my WizardDialog or at least for my whole editor:

```
  public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
      ...
      PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(parent, 
         "my.plugin.help.general");
   }
```

Note: This question originally contained two questions.  I have removed the first (unanswered part) to be posted elsewhere.

Comment: Note to self: 1) Using a contextual ID that includes periods is a recipe for disaster. my.plugin.help.general does not work. you must use my.plugin.help_general when referencing help_general. 2) Must not specify  the plugin name in the help_contexsts.xml file. Use help_general.

Comment: @Jason: if you have managed to answer (part of) your question, you could post an actual answer (and even select your own post as the official answer - no rep gain involved in this case)

Comment: @VonC answered it and created my original question more directly here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021719/eclipse-gef-editpart-contextual-help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how you do it:
1) I created a help_contexts.xml file. Don't have periods in the context id. Don't include your plugin name in there.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?NLS TYPE="org.eclipse.help.contexts"?>
<contexts>
   <context  id="help_general" >
        <description>test</description>
        <topic label="test" href="http://domain.com/help.html"/>
   </context>
</contexts>
```

2) I referenced this file in my plugin.xml Don't include the plugin-id if you are referencing your own plugin.

```
 <extension
         point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
         <contexts file="help_contexts.xml">
         </contexts>
   </extension>
```

3) I added a line in my build.properties to include this file in the bin directory (bin.includes = help_contexts.xml, ... ). Note your Bundle-SymbolicName in your Manifest.MF (also visible in your plugin.xml editor). Example: my.plugin

4) Set the context id in the WizardPage (credit goes to @VonC)

```
public class MyWizardPage extends WizardPage
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench.getHelpSystem.setHelp(parent, "my.plugin.help_general");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For the main question, I am not sure about your setHelp second parameter. See [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.ua/msg00638.html):

> In the method call

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp()
```

> second parameter is the `contextID`.
>   It should be prefixed with the `pluginID` like : "`pluginID.contextID`".
>   Now I was not sure where to find the plug-in ID for my plug-in.
>   So I used the value of this property :  <del>`Bundle-Name`</del> `Bundle-Symbolic-Name` from `MANIFEST.MF` as the plug-in ID.
>   Now it works.

---

For the sidenote (help for `WizardDialog`), [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.platform.ua/msg00365.html) might help (from David Kyle
and his blog "[Eclipse RCP](http://richclientplatform.blogspot.com/)"):

> We set the context id in our wizard page.

```
public class MyWizardPage extends WizardPage
    public void createControl(Composite parent) {
        PlatformUI.getWorkbench.getHelpSystem.setHelp(parent, 
MyPluginActivator.ID + ".mycontexthelpid");
    }
}
```

> and we set help for the wizard dialog.

```
WizardDialog dialog = new WizardDialog(.....);
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getHelpSystem().setHelp(dialog.getShell(), 
"mycontexthelp.id");
```

> We don't override `performHelp()`.
>
> As for the help context id. Define a context xml file in your plugin.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?NLS TYPE="org.eclipse.help.contexts"?>
<contexts>
    <context id="mycontexthelpid" >
        <description>My wizard help.</description>
        <topic label="Wizard help" href="reference/wizard/help.xhtml"/>
    </context>
</contexts>
```

> in your plugin

```
<plugin>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.help.contexts">
        <contexts file="mywizard.xml" plugin="com.mypluginid"/>
    </extension>
</plugin>
```

> A common problem is messing up the plugin and context help ids. You can set 
>   a couple of break points to see which context id is being requested.

Comment: For the first part, I entered a bogus string in there by accident, but I still am not sure how to apply this to GEF EditParts. 

For the second part, the key was adding the reference in the WizardPage. Thanks!

Comment: Note: You want to use Bundle-SymbolicName and not Bundle-Name.

Comment: @Jason: thank you for the feedback. I have updated my answer accordingly